# Which unreal 5 base class should I use

Tags: unreal

I am trying to create an array of objects in unreal 5 populated with questions. Can someone tell me the proper base class to use.

I've tried scene components, actor components and the bare bones and none seem to be the right fit.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "Objects in Unreal 5 populated with questions"? What are 'questions'? Are they literal questions written in text that are in a level or something else?